# Binary relation over ordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm reading some text about binary relations and the author is about to introduce the concept of **reflexivity**. Before doing this he gives an example of a relation that is not reflexive.

> Similarly, the relation “$(x, y) = (y, x)$” over ordered pairs sometimes relates ordered pairs to themselves (for example, $(0, 0) = (0, 0)$), but sometimes does not (for example, $(1, 0) \neq (0, 1)$)

I can't understand how this relations can be a binary one because we always have only one tuple. And how can we even check if two tuples relate to each other?. I mean let's say we want to check if $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ relate to each other by this relation. For me it seems that only the first tuple will participate in the relation and the other one is just ignored.

I understand relation "less than" ($x < y$) over natural numbers. For example, we have two numbers 1 and 3  and we see that they relate to each other, because 1 < 3. But that relation over pairs is very weird to me. I'd be grateful if someone could explain how to deal with it and how I can treat similarly like the "less than" relation.

I'm sorry if my question is too vague or something, but I hope it's clear what I'm worrying about here.

Comment: Well, the writing is a bit unclear.  Perhaps they want to mean to define a new relation between ordered pairs in which $(x,y)\sim (y,x)$.  Actually, now that I think of it, this makes more sense.  This relation is not reflexive after all, since $(1,2)\not \sim (1,2)$.  In any case, if you are looking for a simple example of a non-reflexive relation, this works.

Comment: @lulu I'm not sure, but I think that you meant $ a = d\  \&\  b = c $ in your definition of the relation. If so it makes sense for me

Comment: I now think my first comment was not correct, so I'll delete it.  I meant what I wrote at the time, but now I think they really meant $(x,y)\sim (y,x)$.  As a general note:  I don't think it is wise to use the "=" notation for this relation.  It's certainly not what one generally means by "=" and this relation is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: @lulu and this is exactly what I don't understand. How do we define $∼$? How do we know that $(1, 2)$ doesn't relate to $(1, 2)$ by $∼$?

Comment: In fact, it would be a bit clearer for me if you agreed that $(a,b) ∼ (c, d) \leftrightarrow a = d\  \& \ b = c $. Then we would know for sure that $(1, 2)$ doesn't relate to $(1,2)$, but relates to $(2,1)$. But you said that this is not correct :(

Comment: Yes, that's what I believe they intend.

Comment: To clarify (since I changed my reading);  I believe the relation they mean is $(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff a=d\,\;\&\,\; b=c$, just as you say.  So $(1,2)\not \sim (1,2)$ because here $a\neq d$ (or because $b\neq c$ but we only need one of these).  Indeed, the only points which are related to themselves are the points of the form  $(x,x)$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much for you help. Now I believe I understand this much better.